# ONVIF CreateOSD() returns 'Configuration Token does not exist'

Tags: python, onvif, zeep

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

camera = ONVIFCamera(<host>, <port>, <user>, <passwd>, adjust_time=True)
camera.create_media_service()
osd = camera.media.create_type('CreateOSD')
osd.OSD = {
    'token': 'token0',

    'Position': {
        'Type': 'UpperLeft',
    },
    'TextString': {
        'PlainText': 'TEST',
        'Type': 'Plain',
    },
    'Type': 'Text',
    'VideoSourceConfigurationToken': 'token1',
}
response = camera.media.CreateOSD(osd)
print(response)
```

This is my whole code.

When I call GetServiceCapabilities(), OSD returns True so I think my camera does support OSD.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by adding `VideoSourceConfigurationToken`.

Final code:

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

camera = ONVIFCamera(<host>, <port>, <user>, <passwd>, adjust_time=True)

camera.create_media_service()

profiles = camera.media.GetProfiles()

osd = camera.media.create_type('CreateOSD')
osd.OSD = {
    'token': 'token0',

    'Position': {
        'Type': 'UpperLeft',
    },
    'TextString': {
        'PlainText': 'TEST',
        'Type': 'Plain',
    },
    'Type': 'Text',
    'VideoSourceConfigurationToken': profiles[0].VideoSourceConfiguration.token,
}
response = camera.media.CreateOSD(osd)
print(response)
```